# PTIJ: Can't find the fifth chelek of shulchan aruch

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

People keep telling me that I need to get the fifth section of Shulchan Aruch. I'm not really sure how everyone seems to know that I don't already have this chelek, but since so many people have been recommending it, I've been really trying to find a copy.

Some fellow I met on the internet offered to sell me a copy if I would wire him $5,000, but after I did I think he must have forgotten to send it and I can't get a hold of him now.

Can anyone give me any direction where I could find myself a copy of the 5th chelek of Shulchan Aruch?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: For those who don't get it, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85066/4794

Comment: see http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?cat_id=4&topic_id=2355213&forum_id=771 about the sixth chelek...

Comment: Did the guy who sold it type IN ALL CAPS AND USE GRAMMAR BADLY?

Comment: I really did not get it. Why not include a summary of the idea as well as move the link into the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might not be so advisable to try to get the fifth chelek. After all, Rambam discusses the fifth chelek in his commentary to Avos (11:16), and although he begins by noting that it is permissible (והחלק החמישי והוא הרשות ) a few lines later he quotes the mussar books which warn against using it excessively ( וספרי המוסר מזהירים מלהרבות בו).

Answer (score 7):

In [the question you linked to](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85066/16354), it says in the name of Rav Chaim that it was unwritten.  However, Rav Chaim was mistaken, as [Common Sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Sense_(pamphlet)) was written in 1776 by Thomas Paine.

You can buy it from Amazon [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1557094586).

Comment: No! Thomas Paine revealed to people that he was the intellectual heir to a long chain of secret kabbalists going back to the Rashbi. Rav Chaim wasn't mistaken, it's just that he rejected the notion that Thomas Paine had truly receieved this mesorah, similar to how many rabbis rejected how R' Moshe de Leon received the Zohar!

Comment: Chas Veshalom!  No Rabbis ever challenged or rejected R' Moshe de Leon's Mesorah!  I should flag your comment for Kefirah!

Comment: *some rabbis, I should say. ;)

Comment: Chas Veshalom! No Rabbis ever challenged or rejected Thomas Paine's Mesorah! I should flag your comment for Kefirah!

Comment: @Yez Excellent - lol!

Answer (score 6):

If you give me a bounty of 500 on every answer I post this month, I'll get you a copy.

Answer (score 4):

It just depends what edition you own. Shulchan Arukh started off as just four Chalakim, but as more and more commentaries were added, they eventually split it into five Chalakim because it would no longer all fit in just four. I've heard some printers are now splitting Shulchan Arukh into over 20 Chalakim!

Answer (score 2):

It went the way of the other [395](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.14b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) chapters of Avodah Zarah.

Comment: What an appropriate name for Purim Torah season.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that you don't realize what the problem really is...

It's called **common** sense. That means that everyone has the same sense at the same time. Everyone owns it communally, and by everyone, I mean all of humanity. You can't own a copy yourself. You have to share it with all the others. Your friend is just plain selfish by not letting you use it.